# IntelliJ JUnit5 ClassNotFoundError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5

When trying to run my TestFactory I get this error:

```
Mär 20, 2017 3:39:05 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
INFORMATION: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter, junit-vintage]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opentest4j/TestAbortedException
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.<clinit>(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:47)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.TestFactoryMethodResolver.resolveMethod(TestFactoryMethodResolver.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.TestMethodResolver.resolveElement(TestMethodResolver.java:63)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.tryToResolveWithResolver(JavaElementsResolver.java:164)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.lambda$resolve$8(JavaElementsResolver.java:155)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1548)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.resolve(JavaElementsResolver.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.lambda$resolveForAllParents$4(JavaElementsResolver.java:128)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.resolveForAllParents(JavaElementsResolver.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.resolveMethod(JavaElementsResolver.java:65)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolveSelectors$3(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.resolveDiscoveryRequest(JupiterTestEngine.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:109)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:79)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more
```

however, when running this from commandline (mvn test) it's working.

IDE: IntelliJ 2016.3.3
Java: 1.8
Project SDK: Java 1.8

Libarier:

```
ant-1.8.2.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
junit-4.12.jar
junit-jupiter-api-5.0.0-M3.jar
junit-jupiter-engine-5.0.0-M3.jar
transform-executor-java-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
transform-util-java-4.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
xmlunit-1.5.jar
```

I don't get it...

Comment: You say JUnit 5 in the title, but the pom brings in JUnit 4.  Which is it?  Try adding the opentest4j dependency to your pom.xml.  Make sure the version has that missing class.

Comment: I had a similar problem, which arose when running the tests by Maven on a Bamboo build server. The problem started occurring although no relevant change was made in the POM and probably it was caused by a bug in Bamboo. Nevertheless, the solution from @Jens did solve the problem!

Answer (score 7):

You have to add `opentest4j-1.0.0-M1.jar` to your classpath

Add the following dependency to your pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opentest4j/opentest4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opentest4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentest4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using Maven to Debug my project, I actually use JUnit 5. (Only reason I try to make it work in an ide)

Comment: If you aren't using maven, add the jUnit jar file as library file to your project

Comment: @JudeNiroshan He shouldn't do it. If it is a maven Project, all dependencies should be added to the pom. and it is a maven Project: `commandline (mvn test) `

Comment: @PeterLawrey excactly the same message?

Comment: @Jens no, sorry, a different missing class when trying to JUnit5. This is the third class I have tried to fix since InteliJ migrated to Junit 5. :/

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit jars may be out of date.

1. Delete the ones listed in the dependencies of the project
2. Invoke the quick-fix on an `@Test` annotation
3. Select `Add JUnit5 to classpath`
4. Select your desired Jar location